# Getting SyntaxError with pd.DataFrame(ticker: data.c)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, syntax-error

```
def load_tickers(ticker):
     fname = ( '%s.csv' % ticker.lower())
     data = pd.read_csv( fname, header = None, parse_dates = ['Date'],
                  names =['Date','Open','High','Low','c','Adj Close','Volume'])
     data = data.set_index('Date')
     x = pd.DataFrame(ticker: data.c)
     print(x)

load_tickers('AAPL')
```

I tried running my code but for some reason it's raising a SyntaxError:

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Please do not post errors as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to pass a dictionary and forgot curly brackets. Try this one:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({ticker: data.c})
```